# remove duplicate items in a cascading combo box VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

so I have a series of cascading combo boxes, which are populated dependant on the value of the first box as follows:

ID(pre - populated) > Licence number > State > Name

I am populating the comboboxes using the following bit of code:

```
If cmb_Project.ListIndex <> -1 Then
            cmb_State.Clear
           strSelected = cmb_Licence.Value

           LastRow = Worksheets("Entitlement Owners").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

           Set rngList = Worksheets("Entitlement Owners").Range("c2:c" & LastRow)
           Set rngCompany = Worksheets("Entitlement Owners").Range("b2:b" & LastRow)

           For Each rngCompany In rngList

                 If rngCompany.Value = strSelected Then

                      cmb_State.AddItem rngCompany.Offset(, -1)

                 End If

           Next rngCompany

      End If
```

below is a sample layout of the data I have

```
001      SA 763 Name 1
002     SA  547 Name 2
004     SA  2250    Name 3
004     SA  2250    Name 4
```

So in Combobox 1, I have: 001,002,003,004 (which is correct)

when I select 004 in the first box, the second box populates with: SA,SA which is not what I want.

I have been trying to follow the following [example](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=101908) which allegedly will remove duplicates, but doesn't allow for the comparison I'm doing.

does anybody know how I can remove the duplicates from the search range?

Comment: I see the problem but you description is somewhat confusing. Your code searches in column `C` but you say *"when I select 004 in the first box"* which corresponds to column `A`. Also `Set rngCompany =...` in your code is useless because you immediately assign something else to the variable. I suggest you review the question and edit it.

Comment: @A.S.H -  in relation to your first comment, the first selection is stored in the variable `strselected`, the search in row A is just to find the last active row.
also, I don't understand where I'm assigning a different value to `rngcompany`? its used in a For loop, and then used to compare against the selected string?

Comment: But `004` is in column `A` isn't it?

Comment: `Set rngCompany = Worksheets("Entitlement Owners").Range("b2:b" & LastRow)` followed immediately by `For Each rngCompany In rngList`; the first assignment is useless.

Comment: @A.S.H yes it is, but b combobox 1 (which contains the numbers 001,002,003 etc) is populated in another part of the code (when the form loads) so its irrelevant to this combobox, save for needing to send the selected value to the vaairable identified earlier.

Comment: Ok so your only  for now is to remove the duplicates when populating `cmb_State` from column `B` for matches of `strSelected` in column `C`, is that right?

Comment: @A.S.H yeah that's correct! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove duplicates when populating a list, you can use a dictionary, then set the combo's list property to the dictionary's keys. i.e.

```
Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each rngCompany In rngList
    If rngCompany.value = strSelected Then dict(rngCompany.Offset(, -1).text) = 0 ' add key to dict
Next rngCompany
cmb_State.List = dict.Keys
```

Comment: thanks for providing that, I just wanted to understand how the scripting dictionary removes the duplicate values?

Comment: @scb998 the dictionary is a "Set" object that ensures the uniqueness of its keys. Whenever you reference an existing key, the same entry will be assigned, no keys are duplicated. Take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4(v=vs.84).aspx) for more info.

Comment: Brilliant - thanks very much! so just clarifying, if the key is set to `0`, then it wont allocate anything to the key (ie, I wont see a bunch of `0`'s in my combobox)?

Comment: unfortunately its throwing an application defined or object defined error when it attempts to set the dictionary key.

Comment: Do you have errors such as `#NA` or `#REF` etc. in the cells? I can't see any other reason for failure honestly, you need to check it with your data. In the worst case, you can place some `On Error Resume Next` before the loop and see if the combo is populated correctly.